# Autofill Outlook 2010 Subject Line

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Can someone tell me how to set a consistent subject line in Outlook 2010, if there is a way?

What I have done in the past, before upgrading to 2010, was set up a link on a toolbar with a hyperlink that contains a blank email address but with a subject entered.

Do you know if this will work in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 2):

The mailto:?Subject=Foo method you used before will work just fine in Outlook 2010.